# Calculate the value of a field based on the values of other fields

Tags: splunk

I have a some fields like this:

```
Group_servers|Name_server|Status**
Group1| server1|OK                
Group1| server2|OK  
Group2| server1|OK  
Group2| server1|No data  
Group2| server1|Yellow
Group2| server1|
```

I want to get the result as shown below

```
Group_servers|Status
Group1|OK                
Group1| No data
```

Сonditions for the formation of status groups are as follows:

```
1. If at least one server in the group has the status "No data" or the field is empty, the status for the group is " No data" 
2. If at least one server in the group has the "Yellow" status, the status for the group is " Yellow"
3. If all servers in the group have the status "OK", the status for the group is " OK"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways, one may be clearer than the other

`| fillnull value="No data" Status | stats values(Status) as StatusList by Group_servers` will give you something like the following

```
Group_servers|StatusList
------------------------
Group1       |OK
------------------------
Group2       |No data
             |Yellow
------------------------
```

You can then use `mvfind` to determine what values are present for each group.

`| fillnull value="No data" Status | stats values(Status) as StatusList by Group_servers | eval Status=if(isnotnull(mvfind(StatusList,"No data")),"NoData",( isnotnull(mvfind(StatusList,"Yellow")),"Yellow","OK"))`

As an alternative, you could do something like the following, which just assigns a numeric score to each Status, and then gets the minimum for each group.

`eval status_code=case(Status="OK",2, Status="Yellow",1,1==1,0) | stats min(status_code) as min_status_code by Group_servers | eval Status=case(min_status_code=2,"OK",min_status_code=1,"Yellow",1==1,"No data")`